Passing multiple arguments during langchain chain.invoke()
I am experimenting with a langchain chain by passing multiple arguments.
Here is a scenario:
TEMPLATE = """Task: Generate Cypher statement to query a graph database.
Instructions:
Use only the provided relationship types and properties in the schema.
Do not use any other relationship types or properties that are not provided.

You are also provided with contexts to generate cypher queries. These contexts are the node ids from the Schema.
{schema}

Some examples of contexts:
{context}

The question is:
{question}"""

prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(template=TEMPLATE)
chain = (
    {
     "schema": schema,
     "context": vector_retriever_chain | extract_relevant_docs, 
     "question": RunnablePassthrough()
    }
    | prompt
)
chain.invoke("my question?")

In this chain, I am getting some context from a vector retriever which I am passing to a function called extract_relevant_docs() that will parse the result and get format I want.
The tricky part here is the variable 'schema' which I also want to supply to design my prompt. How can I pass these variables during the chain.invoke().
Thank you

Sorry, I didn't the challenge your are facing with this code. Can you please let us know what is the challenge/error you are facing with this code if 'schema' variable is populated before building the chain?

@SubashKunjupillai
I have a graph db from neo4j, whose schema I want to supply to the prompt.
I would like to ask a question like:
chain.invoke('can you find me who wrote the article?') 

now, this question will be utilized by the vector_retriever_chain as the 'query', and it gives me a result which will be a 'context' passed to the model through prompts. But I am clueless how i can also supply schema, because when the prompt get's created, i also want the model to see the actual schema from the graph (schema = Neo4jGraph.schema).
Hope it makes sense.
Thank you

You can pass multiple inputs in chain.invoke() by forming them as a dict, for example chain.invoke(input={"context": context, "schema": schema})

I finallly figure that. That was a total oversight. But thank you
